# How to do asynchronous requests in frontend when using Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am new to Vue and Nuxt and I have a question concerning asynchronous requests. I have understood that by using `asyncData` and `axios` in Nuxt I can fetch data which can then be rendered in the frontend. However the problem now is that the app will wait until the data has been fetched before displaying anything.

So how can I make sure the app renders something, then runs the asynchronous request in the frontend (just like Vue does with the `created` lifecycle method) but at the same time also renders the data on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned Nuxt will first fulfil any asynchronous call you put into `asyncData`. Once this is done it'll start to render your view, render in this context means it'll simply replace your component tree on the first view with html. All of this happens on your server, the user wont even see any of this.

After that the page gets delivered to the client, already pre-rendered with the data you've been fetching on `asyncData`, if you don't want that to happen simply don't use the `asyncData` method to fetch data.

Everything that you want to fetch on the clientside, basically just put into the vue `mounted` hook as described [here](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/async-data-components/).

So to sum it up: Calls inside of `asyncData` will be done before rendering and by the time of delivery already show up in the users browser. Every call inside of `mounted` will done normally on the client side.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I understand that there is no way to deliver the pre-rendered code (including the data from the request) to clients that don't support asynchronous JavaScript requests (for example Google bots) while at the same time delivering non-pre-rendered code to clients that support JS and run the asynchronous requests in the frontend.

Comment: @phpheini What else is the issue then? Did I miss something?

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is this:

Google bot --> gets pre-rendered code || 
User with JavaScript enabled --> gets code without pre-rendered data, data will be fetched in the frontend asynchronously

Comment: @phpheini I'm pretty sure that's not possible with nuxtjs itself, because what you said in your previous comment pretty much sums it up. Nuxt doesn't care what your client is. Also note that the crawlers execute synchronous javascript, so you can't get away with deleting the fetched data in the mounted hook and re-fetching it for the user.